# Compound English word with most etymologies

Tags: english, etymology, borrowing

There are many English words with two different core etymologies, often Latin + Greek. For example:

> **Claustrophobia** – from the Latin **claustrum** meaning "confined space" and Greek **φόβος** (phobos) meaning "fear".

Are there English words with multiple different roots? I'm okay counting Latin differently from Romance, for example, as the path to English is different. I wouldn't count words that are Germanic as from anything other than "Germanic".  It doesn't feel like a borrowing unless we got it from somewhere distinct other than "straight up through the family tree"

I know you can add an "-ic" to words, which comes through French, or "-al" which is through French < Latin < Etruscan. "rechanneling" is  "re-" from French, "channel" from French via a bunch to Sumerian, "-ing" from English/Germanic

Any ones that aren't just adding something small like that?

Comment: The most obvious candidate I can think of would be the humorous (and deliberately misspelt) _hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobic_ (‘afraid of long words’), which at a rough count has at least nine elements that can be individually etymologised. Sadly, I don’t think it’s made it into any dictionaries yet, so it’s debatable whether it’s an English word or not.

Comment: That's not multiple etymologies, that's a single etymology showing the compounding of elements derived from different languages. Please could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't quite explain that clearly.  I mean "words that show elements derived from different languages"

Answer (score 6):

*Remacadamized* (Latin/French, Gaelic, Hebrew, Greek, English) isn't in the OED, but *Macadamized* is.